# How to Create Charts With DataTables Inside DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, tabs, dataset

does anyone know how can I create different charts with different datatables inside dataset? Let's say I have 3 datatables inside dataset, I want to create 3 charts out with 1 chart=1datatable data. I tried different ways but could not get it work..

This is what I have done so far for my codes:

```
Chart Chart2 = new Chart();
                Chart2.DataSource = ds;
                Chart2.Width = 600;
                Chart2.Height = 350;

                Chart2.Series.Add(new Series());
                Chart2.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                {
                    List<object> lst2 = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        Chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["DEPARTMENT"], new object[] { row["MAX"], row["MIN"], row["AVG"], row["PERCENTILE25"], row["PERCENTILE50"], row["PERCENTILE75"] });
                }

                Chart2.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;

                //if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                //{
                //    string title2 = (tg2.Rows[0]["TITLE"].ToString());
                //    Chart2.Titles.Add(title2);
                //}
                //create chartareas
                ChartArea ca2 = new ChartArea();
                ca2.AxisX = new Axis();
                ca2.AxisY = new Axis();
                Chart2.ChartAreas.Add(ca2);

                //databind
                Chart2.DataBind();
                Chart2.Visible = true;

                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                panel.HeaderText += item.Text;
                container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                //panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
                panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
                panel.Controls.Add(Chart2);
```

After creating the charts, I would like to add them to the tab panel.

Appreciate if someone can provide me guidance on this for me to continue. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set whole DataSet as datasource of Chart, You can select individual DataTable as given below code.

```
Chart Chart2 = new Chart();
Chart2.DataSource = ds.Table[0]; //or ds.Table["TableName"] select appropriate DataTable   
Chart2.Width = 600;
```

Comment: hi, but the thing is I do not know how many datatables are there in the dataset. So I want to loop through each datatables in the dataset and create the chart. Could you suggest me solution for that? Thanks a lot for your reply and help!!

Comment: obviously. You must know what you are displaying in the chart.